# The use of the grammar structure "as being"

Tags: grammar

It was used in [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/GzTrKccmj_I). It is at 6 minute and 17 second.

> This appears to be photograph of wounded solders in a hospital. I am going to go ahead and call it **as being** by Mathew Brady.

I cannot quite get the grammar. Could the speaker omit the *as being* there? I feel the sentence would do fine without it. If am wrong, tell me please why.

Comment: Personally, I think this use of ***call*** is at the very least "slangy" - in any remotely "formal" context I'd expect ***identify, label, classify, designate,*** or similar. So far as I can see, the cited example is syntactically equivalent to ***The witness identified the accused as** [being] **the man who hit her***. In both cases the word ***being*** is "optional" - though for some reason it seems more suitable to include it in OP's example, but not in mine.

Comment: "Call" here has the meaning "declare", so the meaning is "I am going to go ahead and declare it as being by Mathew Brady", where "it" is anaphoric to the referent of "this". You could conceivably drop "as being" but there's little point since it would only be treated as a case of ellipsis, with the missing words understood.

Comment: I'm going to define this **as being** an easy question to answer. Others might categorize it **as being** difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This appears to be photograph of wounded solders in a hospital. I am going to go ahead and call it as being by Mathew Brady."

Semantic parse:

**This usage is spoken**: "I'm going to go ahead and call it as being x".

**To call something** is sports' lingo for what a referee does during a game: **to call a foul or to call a play**. For example. It has come to mean: to say something about something, to define it.

When looking at a picture or listening to something wherethe person who took the picture or recorded the music or speech, respectively, is not clear, it would be standard AmE spoken English to say: I'm going to call it as being by [some photographer or painter or musician].

This would be used for anything where identifying a person is the issue.

Also, very used: I'm going to call it as I see it. You did steal the money. [Let's say you are having an argument, and you say you did not do something bad. The other person can say that sentence to you.]

Who took the picture? Who is the photography by? Who is the man in the photo? Who is the person recording the message or music?

"I'm going to **call it as being** John [who took the picture OR made the recording OR who is in the picture].

In this type of case, **as being** is necessary.

- I'm going to go ahead and call it as being x"

**Go ahead** implies there has been hesitation until that point in time.

"As being x" is in line with : x is identified as being [some person or thing].

Comment: I guess no one is really interested in how this works. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

**(going to go ahead and) call it as being** is a verbose and somewhat informal way of saying

> venture to say that it is ...

To "call" in this sense means "to make and announce a judgment or determination", as an umpire or referee calls a play in a sport, or the doctor in charge declares time of death when a patient has died.

> OK, I'm calling it. Time of death 11:53.

**it** there can be vaguely referential, referring to the situation at hand.

**call it** doesn't take a prepositional phrase complement.

> I'm going to call it by Matthew Brady <sup>NO</sup>

Comment: The question is from a video. I don't think verbosity applies here.  "I'm going to call it by Matthew Brady" is missing something without "as being". It also could mean: I'm going to call it "By Michael Brady". And that would mean it is a title, rather than being a photography taken by Michael Brady.

Comment: It wouldn't be idiomatic to say "I'm going to *call it* by Matthew Brady" under any circumstances.  That's not how **call it** is used.

Comment: ***I misread*** your "NO" as I don't post mistakes in block quotes like that. But, in fact, you never even explain the "as being" part, which is actually the question. I answered it and was dv'ed. Go figure.....

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think **as** is an extremely difficult word to explain.

Comment: With a visual or aural identification situation, you have to have "as being". The issue is not "as".

Comment: You cannot eliminate **as** but you can elminate **being** there.  *I call it as by Matthew Brady* is OK.  *I call it by Matthew Brady* is not, not really. Depends on how far you're willing to bend **call it**.

Comment: The question is not what you can eliminate. The question is: Is this natural speech or not? People talk like that. People say that kind of thing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As we know very well on account of being drummed into our heads right  since the beginning of the learning of english about keeping the verb 'call ' off the preposition 'as ' , we may find it odd to see  'as ' ensconcing itself by being paired with ' being ' on the excuse that it is going to play the part of a phrase in order to hold  the meaning announce or  recognize or declare , which , I think , can be taken as they are in the given sentence . If at all , we are insisted on the usage of the verb 'call ' , we had better watch over it to be not attached with 'as ' , the pair of which being considered a taboo in the eyes of any grammarian.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please note that this is a site for *learners* of English, and even I have a hard time parsing it ... you might want to check the Help Center article [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).